# Is $\ker T = \ker T^*$ for idempotent operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, direct-sum, idempotents

Recall that if $T : V \to W$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional inner product spaces, then $T^* : W \to V$ is defined as the unique linear map satisfying $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^*w \rangle$ for all $v \in V$ and $w \in W$. Notice that $w \in \ker T^*$ iff $T^* w = 0$ iff $0 = \langle v, T^* w \rangle = \langle Tv, w \rangle$ for all $v \in V$, so $\ker T^* = T(V)^\perp$.

Consequently, if $S : V \to V$ is linear, then $V = S(V) \oplus S(V)^\perp = S(V) \oplus \ker S^*$. If $S : V \to V$ is also idempotent ($S^2 = S$), then $Sv = v$ iff $S(Sv) = v$ shows that $S(V)$ is the fixed points of $S$, and the only fixed point in the kernel is $0$, so $S(V) + \ker S$ is direct with dimension $\dim V$ by rank-nullity, so $S(V) \oplus \ker S = V = S(V) \oplus \ker S^*$.

Is $\ker S = \ker S^*$? In general, $A \oplus B = A \oplus B'$ does not imply $B = B'$, so I suspect not.

Comment: Not in general, no. This will only be true for *self-adjoint* idempotent operators. Pick any non-self-adjoint idempotent operator, such as $(x, y) \mapsto (x - y, 0)$, to get a counterexample.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624740/intuition-behind-kert-kert-for-t-a-normal-operator) suggests that normal operators ($T \circ T^* = T^* \circ T$) satisfy this property. Self-adjoint ($T^* = T$) implies normal, but the converse is false. @TheoBendit are you saying that if an idempotent operator is normal, yet not self-adjoint, then it will not satisfy this property?

Comment: I am implicitly claiming that an operator cannot be idempotent, normal, and not self-adjoint all at the same time. Normal is equivalent (at least, in the complex setting) to the eigenspaces being orthogonal, whereas self-adjoint means that the eigenspaces are orthogonal *and* the eigenvalues are real. The fact that idempotent operators satisfy the polynomial equation $z^2 - z = 0$, which has only real roots, implies that the eigenvalues are real anyway (specifically: $0$ and $1$).

Comment: What does it mean for the eigenspaces to be orthogonal - couldn't there be more than 2 eigenspaces? I can prove (with help from the spectral theorem) that over $\mathbb{C}$, $S : V \to V$ is self-adjoint iff $S$ is normal with all real eigenvalues. Why does $v \mapsto (S^2 - S)v = S^2 - Sv$ equaling $v \mapsto 0$ imply that all the eigenvalues of $S$ are real?

Comment: It means that, given two vectors in two different eigenspaces (i.e. corresponding to different eigenvectors), they are orthogonal. Try assuming that $Sv = \lambda v$ for $v \neq 0$, then $0 = (S^2 - S)v = (\lambda^2 - \lambda)v = 0$. Since $v \neq 0$, $\lambda^2 - \lambda = 0$, so $\lambda = 0, 1 \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I assume you mean $S$ is normal iff $S$ **is diagonalizable and** vectors from distinct eigenspaces are orthogonal? Otherwise, a counterexample to "orthogonal eigenspaces $\implies$ normal" is any non-diagonalizable operator with only one eigenvalue, such as most upper-triangular matrices with constant diagonal.

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct. The diagonalisability of $T$ follows from the minimal polynomial (being a divisor of the square-free polynomial $z^2 - z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an idempotent operator $S: V \to V$ let $K$ be its kernel and $P$ its image, so that $V = K \oplus P$. The adjoint operator $S^*$ is also idempotent, and we can see that if $v \in P^\perp$ then $\langle -, S^* v \rangle = \langle S(-), v \rangle = 0$. Therefore $P^\perp \subseteq \ker S^*$. Applying the same logic to $1 - S$ shows that $K^\perp \subseteq \operatorname{im} S$, so $S^*$ has kernel $P^\perp$ and image $K^\perp$.

Thinking of $S$ as a projection to $P$ by killing $K$, then $S^*$ is a projection to $K^\perp$ by killing $P^\perp$. A little thought should convince you that $K = P^\perp$ if and only if the operator $S$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Does idempotent and normal imply self-adjoint?

Comment: @jskattt797 Yes

Comment: What does "applying the same logic to $1 - S$" mean? The 1st paragraph of the OP proves $\ker S^* = S(V)^\perp$, so $(\ker S)^\perp = (\ker ((S^*)^*))^\perp = (S^*(V)^\perp)^\perp = S^*(V)$; thus $S^*$ has kernel $P^\perp$ and image $K^\perp$. Therefore, if $S$ is self-adjoint, then $S = S^*$ has kernel $P^\perp$, i.e. $K = P^\perp$. But how do we show that if $K = P^\perp$, then $S$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: @jskattt797 If $S$ is idempotent with $0$-eigenspace $K$ and $1$-eigenspace $P$, then $(1 - S)$ is idempotent with $0$-eigenspace $P$ and $1$-eigenspace $K$: it is the "complementary" projection which has the roles of $K$ and $P$ interchanged. Since I argued that $P \subseteq \ker S^*$, doing the $(1-S)$ trick shows that $K^\perp \subseteq \ker (1-S^*) = \operatorname{im}(S^*)$. (There are other ways to see this too).

Comment: If $K = P^\perp$ then the $0$-eigenspace $K$ and the $1$-eigenspace $P$ of the operator $S$ are orthogonal. This means that $P$ is orthogonally diagonalisable with real eigenvalues, which implies that it is self-adjoint. (This is in fact an if and only if, with the converse direction given by the spectral theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Say $S : V \to V$ has image $I$ and kernel $K$. $S$ is idempotent $\iff$ $I$ is a subspace of its fixed points $\iff$ its fixed points are precisely $I$. Thus $K \cap I = \{0 \}$ (there's only one fixed point in the kernel), so $K + I$ is a direct sum of subspaces, so $V = K \oplus I$ by rank-nullity. Construct orthormal bases $k_1, \dots, k_m$ for $K$ and $i_1, \dots, i_n$ for $I$, so that $\mathcal{B} = k_1, \dots, k_m, i_1, \dots, i_n$ is a basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $S$. Then for all $v \in V$,
$$Sv = S\left( \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i k_i + \sum_{j =  1}^n \beta_j i_j \right) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \beta_j i_j$$
In other words, $S$ maps $v = v_K + v_I$ to $v_I$, the unique part of $v$ in $I$. Conversely, if $S : V \to V$ satisfies $V = K \oplus I$ and $Sv = v_I$ for all $v$, then $S^2 v = S v_I = v_I = S v$ for all $v$, so $S$ is idempotent. In conclusion, $S$ is idempotent $\iff$ $S$ is a ***projection*** (meaning $V = K \oplus I$ and $Sv = v_I$).

The question asks if $K = \ker S^* = I^\perp$ for all projections $S$, which is false. For example,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$$
is a horizontal shear followed by orthogonal projection onto the $x$-axis, which squashes all the points in each kernel coset $(x, y) + K = (x, y) + \mathrm{Span}(-1, 1)$ down to their intersection $(x + y, 0)$ with the $x$-axis (the image, $I = \mathrm{Span}(1, 0)$). It is idempotent (equivalently, it is a projection since $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathrm{Span}(-1, 1) \oplus \mathrm{Span}(1, 0)$, and $(x + y, 0)$ is the $I$ part of $(x, y) = (-y, y) + (x + y, 0)$), but clearly $K \neq I^\perp = $ the $y$-axis.

However, $K = I^\perp$ seems like a property worth investigating. Indeed, it seems like a reasonable use of English to say a projection $S$ (as described above) is an ***orthogonal projection*** iff $K$ and $I$ are orthogonal, i.e. $K = I^\perp$. In fact, $K = I^\perp$ iff $S$ is self-adjoint. Recall that $S^* : V \to V$ has kernel $I^\perp$, which is also the kernel of $S$ if $S = S^*$. Conversely, if $K = I^\perp$, then the aforementioned $\mathcal{B} = k_1, \dots, i_n$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis, so the matrix $[S]_\mathcal{B}$ for $S$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ is diagonal with $1$s and $0$s along the diagonal, whence $[S]_\mathcal{B}$ is Hermitian; it follows that $S = S^*$, as $[S^*]_\mathcal{B}$ is the conjugate transpose of $[S]_\mathcal{B}$.

For a given subspace $U$ of $V$, define a ***projection onto*** $U$ as a projection with image $I = U$. There can be at most one orthogonal projection onto $U$: if $S_1, S_2$ are orthogonal projections onto $U$, then they have the same image $U$ and kernel $U^\perp$, so both transformations map $v = v_U + v_{U^\perp}$ to $v_U$ for all $v \in V$. And an orthogonal projection always exists, given by
$$v \mapsto \sum_{i = 1}^k \langle v, u_i \rangle u_i$$
for any orthonormal basis $u_1, \dots, u_k$ of $U$. It is the unique idempotent, self-adjoint operator with image $U$.